# STM32 NUCLEO-F302R8 UART : RX pin does not trigger RX callback

Tags: stm32, uart, nucleo

I'm using an [STM32 NUCLEO-F302R8](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/98/2e/fa/4b/e0/82/43/b7/DM00105823.pdf/files/DM00105823.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00105823.pdf) and wish to communicate with it using any UART instance (1,2,3) through its RX/TX pins.

So far, I've managed to read from the TX pin but never managed to send messages to it via an RX pin. It simply does not react to any signal I put on any RX pin.

**Any idea what I could try to make any UART RX pin work from somebody who went through a similar experience ?**

All comunications done through USB work and the TX pins output correctly-encoded data (confirmed using a USB-UART conversion cable)

I've used several setups, but the most viable one is with another NUCLEO :

```
PC --(USB TX)-> STM32(1st) --(UART TX)-> STM32(2nd) --(USB TX)-> PC
```

I've tried:

- using USART1, USART2, USART3
- all combinations of solder bridges configurations : SB13 & SB14 on/off, SB62 & SB63 on/off
- 3 different NUCLEO boards to rule out hardware fault
- baudrates 115200 and 9600
- using the USB-UART cable directly on the NUCLEO's RX pin (it's a 3.3V level)
- using the CN3 RX/TX pins

Here are the relevant initialization functions.
Any idea or question is welcome.

Additional notes :

- The project is configured through CubeMX
- It uses DMA and ADC.

```
    /* USART2 init function */
    static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
    {
    
      huart2.Instance = USART2;
      huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
      huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
      huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
      huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
      huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
      huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
      huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
      huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
      huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
      if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
      {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
      }
    
    }
    
    /* USART3 init function */
    static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void)
    {
    
      huart3.Instance = USART3;
      huart3.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
      huart3.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
      huart3.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
      huart3.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
      huart3.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
      huart3.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
      huart3.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
      huart3.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
      huart3.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
      if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart3) != HAL_OK)
      {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
      }
    
    }
    
    /** 
      * Enable DMA controller clock
      */
    static void MX_DMA_Init(void) 
    {
      /* DMA controller clock enable */
      __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();
    
      /* DMA interrupt init */
      /* DMA1_Channel3_IRQn interrupt configuration */
      HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn, 0, 0);
      HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn);
      /* DMA1_Channel5_IRQn interrupt configuration */
      HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel5_IRQn, 0, 0);
      HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel5_IRQn);
      /* DMA1_Channel6_IRQn interrupt configuration */
      HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel6_IRQn, 0, 0);
      HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel6_IRQn);
    
    }
    
    /** Pinout Configuration
    */
    static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
    {
    
      /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    
    }
```

Comment: Get it working without DMA 1st. Make sure that the UART interrupt is enabled in the NVIC, and that RX is enabled to trigger an interrupt in the UART.

Comment: I'm currently on vacation so I cannot test it anytime soon, but I'll try to remember to try the "no-DMA" route. Although the first thing to try would be to create a specific minimalist project to debug this particular issue. Concerning the RX Interrupt, the program does fine with the USB link so I don't think there's anything wrong on that side.